# Create new PHP project in Eclipse (existing sources)

Tags: php, eclipse

I have a PHP project sat on a remote server.

Can I create a new project in Eclipse by downloading the sources from the remote server.

If so, some instructions on how to do so please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to do that, at least with [standard install](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/) of Eclipse PHP

You would usually use *"File > Import..."* or *"File > New Project > PHP Project..."* menus for that, but I have never seen this option anywhere in Eclipse.

So this is one of three solutions :

- get a local copy of the php code
- import from source repository (e.g SVN, CVS, Git).  (you do use one of these for your project, do you ?)
- switch to another IDE, **NetBeans**, which support "PHP Application from Remote Server", while being lighter IMHO.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, some projects don't use SVN. I normally use Netbeans, but also do a bit of Android and LUA/Corona so just wanted to try and keep everything 'under one roof'

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the type of source control software.  You can install git, svn or cvs modules.  The steps to take are:

1. Install module for git, svn or cvs
2. Create new {git|svn|cvs} project, enter the server information
3. Then it takes you to what kind of project to create, so create a PHP
   project.  (This assumes that there isn't an eclipse project already
   submitted to version control.)

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am aware of. Even when you remote debug you would still need a copy of the sources locally.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same, by fooling the local system.

- Create a Network Location drive
- Go on your desktop Right click > Add a Network Location
- Choose a custom Network Location
- Pass a Internet IP or network Location

e.g.

```
\\server\share (shared folder)
http://swatantra.info/share (Web Share)
ftp://ftp.swatantra.info (FTP site)
```

- Now it is similar to your normal local drive mapped as (Z:\ or so)
- Go on with your normal project creation stuff