# how to configure codeigniter 2.1.0 framework in eclipse helios ?

Tags: php, eclipse, codeigniter, eclipse-3.6, helios

How can I configure codeigniter 2.1.0 framework in eclipse helios?

Can anybody provide me the link of steps to do this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean configure? I'm using Indigo and intellisense gets all methods, vars etc. correctly without doing anything (just by creating the project i the folder where I put the CI install)

Comment: I am using Helios for PHp but I don't know how to include/use codeigniter 2.1.0 framework with Eclipse Helios....

Comment: Like any other: create a new php project, make it point to the directory you have CI in, and it should pick up everything by itself

Comment: @DamienPirsy, can u please provide link or steps to invoke hello world in eclipse using CI???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the installation manual found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html), and them simply create new PHP project and add the folder with the CI instance to it (click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504720/create-new-php-project-in-eclipse-existing-sources) for details). Simple as that ! Good luck

PS. Eclipse is not setting the framework for you, it just provides you with a PHP IDE, you are the one that does the magic here.