# How to create laravel project using eclipse for PHP Developer

Tags: php, eclipse

I have been assigned a task to create project using laravel 5 framework in Eclipse for PHP Developer.

## Effort

I have downloaded eclipse for php developer and I have also installed Compser plugin from http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/. But when i tried to create project from existing eclipse suddenly close.

I have also tried eclipse composer plugin but I did not get success.

I am not able to create laravel project in eclipse. I have to use composer to maintain dependencies. Please suggest me how to do it.

I am using eclipse mars 1 for php developer.

Answer (score 2):

Duplicate question, answer here : 
[Create new PHP project in Eclipse (existing sources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8504720/create-new-php-project-in-eclipse-existing-sources?rq=1)

Using PDT Eclipse (or install PHP Eclipse plugin) :

1. File -> New -> PHP Project ...
2. In Content box, check Create project at existing location (from existing source)

Comment: ​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​If you think that this question is duplicate to another question, flag or vote to close it (once you have enough rep) instead of posting a new answer.

Comment: I think this is similar to the linked one but different enough to remain a unique question as this one is not specifying that the files reside on a remote server in which case this answer would satisfy the OP

Answer (score -1):

Install the Remote Server Plugin, less troubles.